# Does $\|A^n\| \to 0$ imply that spectral radius of $A$ is less than one?

Tags: linear-algebra

If the spectral radius of a matrix is less than one, then $$\|A^n\|\to 0$$ as $n \to \infty.$

The question: Is the converse is true?

Comment: jordan canonical form might help. have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $$|\lambda|^n\le \|A^n\|$$